# get_template_part causes 500 error

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-template-part

I am trying to list posts in a widget I am working on at the moment. However, when I use the get_template_part function in my loop, my site just keeps loading until I get a 500 http error.

```
    $args       = array(
        'numberposts'      => 10,
        'orderby'          => 'date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => $postType,
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );
    $postsQuery = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $postsQuery->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $postsQuery->have_posts() ) {
            get_template_part( 'content/content', $postType );
        }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

When I comment the `get_template_part` out, everything works just fine. Also the loop seems to loop perfectly through the posts. Just the `get_template_part` is somewhat problematic. I don't have any idea, how I could figure out what the problem is. Any ideas? Maybe I am using it wrong or something?

---

Here's the solution:

I was missing the `$postsQuery->the_post()` in my loop. Also guilemons tip helped, that I needed a folder called content in the same directory where my php file was with the templates.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the template that's causing the 500 error? A 500 error is the servers way of saying "Something went wrong, don't know what, look at the log to see what happened", so check your PHP error logs. Also, your loop never calls `the_post`, so it never progresses, it's an infinite loop

Comment: Also, `'suppress_filters' => true` is bad for performance, and you can improve performance by adding `'post_status' => 'publish'` which simplifies the query, WP adds extra logic for showing your private posts that slows things a little

Comment: Thanks! I will do that! I solved the problem with guilemons answer. Maybe the 500 is just my servers weird way of saying it doesn't like my way of building loops ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_template_part()` function takes filepath relative to the file it is called in. Do you have a folder called 'content' which contains a file `content-posttype.php`? is the 'content' folder located in the same folder as this php file you are calling `get_template_part()` in?

Also, you can modify your while loop as follows:

```
        while ( $postsQuery->have_posts() ) {
          $postsQuery->the_post();
          get_template_part( 'content/content', $postType );//please check the file path.
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `$postsQuery->the_post()` in your loop. That function moves the loop to the next post, without it you're performing an infinite loop.

```
while ( $postsQuery->have_posts() ) {
    $postsQuery->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content/content', $postType );
}
```

`get_template_part()` is irrelevant to the issue. I don't know enough about PHP's internals to be sure, but I suspect it's working when you comment it out because a loop with nothing in it isn't executed.